# Find the point at which the line $L(t) = (5,−4,−3⟩ + t(−2,−5,3)$ intersects the plane $5x + 5y - z = −220$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having issues with what the t outside the vectors signifies, what do I do with it? How can I get from there to the coordinates of $(x,y,z)$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Parameterize the line, substitute, then solve for $t$, then substitute again.

Comment: $t$ is there as a variable to indicate that the line contains the point $(5,-4,-3)$ and every other point that reached by adding some scalar multiple $t\in\Bbb R$ of the direction vector $(-2,-5,3)$ to the first point.

Answer (score 1):

According to @AndrewChin's comment, one has the following system of equations to solve

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
(x,y,z) = (5-2t,-4-5t,-3+3t)\\\\
5x + 5y - z = -220
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

thence we get that
\begin{align*}
5(5-2t) - 5(4+5t) + (3-3t) = -220 \Longleftrightarrow -38t = -228 \Longleftrightarrow t = 6
\end{align*}

Therefore the intersection point is given by $(x,y,z) = (-7,-34,15)$.

Hopefully this helps.